# Python Django url method regex for comma separated string in single quotes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Attempting to regex match a string like so:

> '1,2'

Using Django rest framework `url` method to parse incoming string, I tried this:

```
url(r'^path/to/api/end_point/(?P<player_ids>"\'1,2\'")/',
        PlayerResultsView.as_view(),
        name='get_players)
```

The error I get:

> django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'get_players'
> with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'player_ids': '1,2'}' not
> found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['path/to/api/end_point/(?P<player_ids>"\'1,2\'")/']

**Overall Goal:** pass comma separated string ('1,2,3,4') to REST endpoint, split on the comma and continue processing.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

What you are trying to do is match a fixed string `1,2`. If you want a variable input whether it is `1,2` or `1,2,3,4` or others, then try this regex pattern `[\d,]+` which will capture non-empty string containing any numbers and commas.

```
re_path(r'^path/to/api/end_point/(?P<player_ids>[\d,]+)/', views.some_view),
```

Sample URL would be:

- `http://127.0.0.1:8000/path/to/api/end_point/1,2,3,4/`

### Solution 2

Instead of such variable input in the path, you might be interested in making it query parameters instead. So something like:

```
path('path/to/api/end_point/', views.some_view),
```

Sample URL would be:

- `http://127.0.0.1:8000/path/to/api/end_point/?player_ids=1,2,3,4`

Then, just access it as part of the `request.GET` or `request.query_params` (if using `djangorestframework`) in your view.

```
def some_view(request, **kwargs):
    print(f"{request.GET.get('player_ids')=}")
    print(f"{request.query_params.get('player_ids')=}")
```

Output

```
request.GET.get('player_ids')='1,2,3,4'
request.query_params.get('player_ids')='1,2,3,4'
[08/Sep/2021 01:44:05] "GET path/to/api/end_point/?player_ids=1,2,3,4 HTTP/1.1" 200 17
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but I could not get it to work fully. I ended up going with a POST, easier to pass a Python List that way.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go with a POST, easier to pass more complex parameters.

My URL pattern:

```
url(r'^path/to/api/end_point/',
        PlayerResultsView.as_view(),
        name='get_players)
```

My POST data is an array of player ids:

```
list_of_search_ids = [player1.player_id, player2.player_id]
    data = {'player_ids': list_of_search_ids}
    url = reverse(
        "get_players"
    )
    resp = self.client.post(url, json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```